# Show an Image on a WPF window from a User Control Library

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to show an Image Resource that is stored in a User Control Library, on a WPF Application Window. It works in the design editor, but not at run-time.

```
MyLibrary (User Control Library)
/Resources/user-48.png (Build Action: Resource)
```

---

Wpf Application Window (Separate Project, references MyLibrary)

```
...
<Image 
  Source="pack://application:,,,/MyLibrary;Component/Resources/user-48.png"
  Width="48" Height="48"/>
```

What am I missing here? Please explain why it works in design time, but not run time.

Comment: Any errors that you can see? Try this `Source="/MyLibrary;Component/Resources/user-48.png"` since you are already referencing the assembly in the WPF application.

Comment: I've tried that. No change, and no errors, and no image.

Comment: Can you remove the reference, rebuild the other dll and then re-reference the assembly? Have you tried this?

Comment: I'm able to get it working using a standard .net framework class library... Not sure if there is a difference between a User Control Library and a regular one...

Comment: Just a suggestion, WPF app .net version should be higher or equal to User Control Library. Kindly check that.

Comment: Please try `Source="pack://application:,,/MyLibrary;Component/Resources/user-48.png"`. I know you did right things but if possible try to clean solution and rebuild everything again.

Comment: Not sure if it makes any difference, but the proper writing of the `;component/` part of a Pack URI is with lowercase `c`.

Comment: Besides that, your problem isn't reproducible. Provided that `MyLibrary` is the name of the User Control Library, the library is referenced from the main project, the image file is in a project folder named `Resources` and its Build Action is Resource, `pack://application:,,,/MyLibrary;component/Resources/user-48.png` is a valid URI and just works.